# Magento 1.9.2.1 RWD theme One page checkout progress column showing formatting errors

Tags: onepage-checkout, rwd-theme, rwd, onestepcheckout

[image: formatting error]

so translation seems to be working, however the problem seems that maybe variables are not defined in the progress.phtml, not quite as in there it is directed to

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('billing.progress')
```

now I am stuck as all the template files in the 'base' package do not contain the keyword progress other than progress.phtml and no clue what this function is about

i am aware that the RWD theme package has less files in the folder:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage
```

I am working with a fresh install and hardly any extensions.

Thank you for giving me some clues on how to resolve